# Automatic expiry of objects from Hashmap

Tags: caching, hashmap

I have a static hashmap which I am using to cache objects in it. The objects are of different types including lists and hashmaps.

I want to invalidate the objects from the cache after certain time interval. I could add a timestamp to my objects and invalidate them manually. But, I don't know if there is any way I could find the timestamp of when a list was added to the hashmap.

Any comments or suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have all the objects which you store in your `Hashmap` implement a single `Expirable` interface:

```
public interface Expirable {

    public Date getExpiryDate();
}
```

Once done you'll easily be able to iterate through each element in your `Hashmap` and remove those which have expired.

Answer (score 1):

The Guava interface `com.google.common.cache.Cache` can be accessed as a map by calling `Cache.asMap()`.

Refer to [`CacheBuilder`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) for documentation, specifically the [`expireAfterWrite()`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#expireAfterWrite-java.time.Duration-) method.